# How to make pandas discern the difference between None and NaN in python?

Tags: python, pandas

Some of the items in my data have default value equal to `None` and some default values are simply missing. But seems like pandas doesn't make too much difference between `None` and `NaN` threating them all as NaNs which is somewhat logical cos neither of them is a number but still I'd like to store Nones as Nones and NaNs as NaNs. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `pandas` interprets a column's `dtype` to be numeric, then all nulls `None` or `np.nan` will become `np.nan`.  The only way for pandas to preserve `None` and `np.nan` in the same column is to have the `dtype` be `object`.  However, it is important to point out that if the `dtype` is `object` you lose many of the benefits of having a numeric `dtype` like efficient calculations.

```
pd.Series([1, None, np.nan, 2])

0    1.0
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    2.0
dtype: float64
```

---

```
pd.Series([1, None, np.nan, 2], dtype=object)

0       1
1    None
2     NaN
3       2
dtype: object
```

---

```
s1 = pd.Series([1, None, np.nan, 2])
s2 = pd.Series([1, None, np.nan, 2], dtype=object)

%timeit s1 + 1
%timeit s2 + 1

68 µs ± 3.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
169 µs ± 5.18 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Ah I see! Seems like that's what I need. Thank you!

Comment: And would you please mention at least some of the benefits? Can I do grouping, filtering etc?

Comment: I don't see much benefit from my end.  I can imagine edge use cases where someone wants to preserve `None` separate from `np.nan`.  Or maybe for reporting purposes, they want their table to look a certain way.  Otherwise, I'm not familiar with any substantial benefits of using `dtype` `object`.  I've used it when I wanted a series to track my custom objects, but that isn't normal.

Comment: Yes, you can do filtering and grouping.  But nothing is as efficient.

Comment: aah okay, so the difference is mainly in efficiency, right? Hmm the reason why I'm looking to separate them is because my dataframe is made up of function names, their arguments, default values of the arguments etc so the column 'default_values" sometimes must store `None` indicating that the default val of the corresponding arg is set to `None` and sometimes `Nan` indicating that the default value is missing. How do I do this without separating `Nans` and `Nones` then?

Comment: Don't even worry about it.  Use `dtype=object`.  If you are tracking functions, there is no way you handling that many rows.  Efficiency is probably not your concern.  It should still be plenty fast for your purposes.

Comment: Yeah seems so. Thank you for the help!